# How solve rpm non-readable error

Tags: linux, package, rpm

I am making packege of some python module for ROSA(linux-based OS)

so I have this error:

```
python-dogpile-cache.noarch: E: non-readable (Badness: 1) /usr/share/doc/python-dogpile-cache/changelog.rst 0600
```

So i am making rpm-package of dogpile.cache v 0.6.7. 
My .spec file looks like this.
I couldn't even find some information about error description of rpm. So I ask you about any kind of help.

```
%define oname   dogpile.cache

Name:       python-dogpile-cache
Version:    0.6.7
Release:    1
Summary:    A caching front-end based on the Dogpile lock
Source0:    http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/%{oname}/%{oname}-%{version}.tar.gz
License:    BSD
Group:      Development/Python
Url:        http://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/dogpile.cache
BuildArch:  noarch
BuildRequires:  pythonegg(setuptools)
BuildRequires:  python-dogpile-core

%description
A caching API built around the concept of a "dogpile lock", which allows
continued access to an expiring data value while a single thread generates
a new value.

%prep
%setup -q -n %{oname}-%{version}

%build
python setup.py build

%install
python setup.py install --root=%{buildroot}

%files
%doc LICENSE
%doc README.rst
%doc docs/api.html
%doc docs/changelog.html
%doc docs/core_usage.html
%doc docs/front.html
%doc docs/genindex.html
%doc docs/index.html
%doc docs/py-modindex.html
%doc docs/recipes.html
%doc docs/search.html
%doc docs/usage.html
%doc docs/_sources/api.rst.txt
%doc docs/_sources/changelog.rst.txt
%doc docs/_sources/core_usage.rst.txt
%doc docs/_sources/front.rst.txt
%doc docs/_sources/index.rst.txt
%doc docs/_sources/recipes.rst.txt
%doc docs/_sources/usage.rst.txt
%doc docs/_static/changelog.css
%doc docs/build/changelog.rst
%doc docs/build/requirements.txt
%doc docs/build/unreleased/README.txt
%{py_puresitedir}/dogpile/*.py*
%{py_puresitedir}/dogpile/cache/*.py*
%{py_puresitedir}/dogpile/cache/backends/*.py*
%{py_puresitedir}/dogpile/cache/plugins/*.py*
%{py_puresitedir}/dogpile/util/*.py*
%{py_puresitedir}/dogpile.cache*.egg-info
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not finding any documentation on the error because the error is from rpmlint, not rpm.

rpmlint applies certain heuristics to packages to improve package quality.

The error is due to the permissions 0600 which renders the file unreadable.

Comment: So, as I understand I can do something like chmod 644 to this file?
Anyway thanks for notice about rpmlint

Comment: Yes adding +r to the file should keep rpmlint "happy"